# Variable 'test' is used before being assigned

Tags: typescript

From my code snippet below:

```
export const testIt = (): {
  testPeople: IPeople[];
} => {
  const personId = "Peter03";

// This line has "Variable 'test' is used before being assigned" error:
  let test: IPeople; 
  const clone = {...test};

  getPeopleInfo(personId)
    .then(person => {
      clone.id = person.id;
    });
  const testPeople: IPeople[] = [];

  if (clone) {
    testPeople.push(clone);
  }
  return { testPeople };
};
```

I tried to set test empty: "let test: IPeople = {}".

but I got a new error " Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'PersonInformation': phoneNumber, id, address, and 5 more."

(I'm having a clone here is because the properties of IPeople are read-only.)

Is there any way to fix this error?

Comment: You never assign anything to `test`, whats it's purpose?

Comment: Why do you want to clone `test` before it has been initialized?

Answer (score 1):

You're defining `test` as a variable, but not assigning it any value so it's undefined when you use it in the next line:

```
  let test: IPeople; 
  const clone = {...test};
```

You need to define it as something:

```
  let test: IPeople = { name: "Jim" }; 
  const clone = {...test};
```

`test` is never assigned to anything, or used, so I'm not sure what the purpose of it is!

Do you want to 'get' that information "out" of the promise, so are trying to assign it to this `test`/`clone` object? There's some serious other issues with the code if that's the intent.

Promises are asynchronous, i.e. they 'happen later'. So your function in the `then` will likely happen after the rest of the code has finished.

Your code will run, create the `clone` variable (unassigned), not push it to the array because it's not assigned, then later the `then(person => {` function will run, assign the clone variable, in a 'completed' function. The code that called the function would have just got an empty array!

You want to return a `Promise<IPeople[]>`, so the caller of the function can wait for the response.